# How to put multiple joomla modules in one module position?

Tags: css, joomla

I thought I knew how to do this but something odd is happening.
I put 2 modules in the same module position. I set the Module Class Suffix for both of them to " fouracross".
I add the css...

```
.fouracross {
width: 45%; 
float: left;
border: solid; 1 px;}
}
```

The modules do indeed sit side by side each taking up 45% of the space BUT the text within each module also only takes up 45% of the space in that module!

You can see the result on this experimental page - I've temporarily put a border on the modules so you can see the outline - http://www.cotswoldplayhouse.co.uk/jm3

It seems that the style is being applied both the the module container AND to a container round the text.
Any ideas how to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is because it appears to be applying the `fouracross` class to both the parent **and** the child elements as shown below:

```
<div class="art-block clearfix fouracross">  <<< HERE
   <div class="art-blockheader">
      <h3 class="t">Vouchers</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="art-blockcontent">
      <div class="custom fouracross">  <<< AND HERE

         <p>Cotswold Playhouse vouchers make an ideal present. Any value can be purchased and they can be exchanged for tickets for any event for up to one year after purchase.</p>
         <p>Full details are available here</p>

      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Go to the following location:

```
modules/mod_YOURMODULE/tmp/default.php
```

and will most likely have something like this:

```
<div class="custom <?php echo $moduleclass_sfx ?>">
```

which you can change to:

```
<div class="custom">
```

Comment: I think that would work, but it would effect ALL custom HTML modules as that bit is common code. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The thing is module class suffixes should only ever be applied to the parent, thus should only ever us used once. This allows one to target it using CSS to apply different styling

Answer (score 1):

You have to change rule to affect only the **container** and not **inner divs**.

This should work:

```
.art-block.fouracross {
  width: 45%; 
  float: left;
  border: solid; 1 px;
}
```